# Determine which of running servers, an emacsclient attached to?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I planed to starting emacs from the the `start.sh` as

```
$ head start.sh
#! /bin/bash
{
    #starting emacs servers
    emacs --daemon=orging
    emacs --daemon=coding
    #waiting...
    #invoke emacsclients
    emacsclient -c -s "orging" &
    emacsclient -c -s "coding" &
    ......
    } &> /dev/null
```

Two clients run respectively under servers of `orging` and `coding`.

A problem occurred to  this situation is that the invoked running clients are not labelled with appropriate server names.

So a manual steps of testing might be need to determine who is who.

As an alternative, the servers could   be scheduled with one running at the top , the other at the end  after  starting from in the `start.sh`,

How could determine which server a client attached in a straightforward way on a working frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the variable `server-name` - interactively with `C-h v server-name RET`.